# Specific order (sql)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got a model `Pupil`, which has got field `score`. I need to make a list with strange rule: order by score (DESC) but (!) all scores that more than 100 should ordered as zero:

```
Pupil.all( :order => 'score DESC' ...?)
100
86
34
21
6
3
1
0
143
125
354
0
456
0
0
```

**I can order it using ruby, but I need sql**

Aslo I can create additional field in db for storing data like 
`new_score = score > 100 ? 0 : score`
but I think we can make sql without it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do order by 'score > 100' (order the booleans), then order by score. All those with score > 100 will be pre-ordered by the boolean, and the sub-order will order the other scores after the >100 ones.

I hope this was clear enough and what you were looking for :)

Comment: Just be aware that in every database the sorting of booleans may be different. You may be safer if you write a full: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN score > 100 THEN score ELSE 0 END` (if your database understands it)

Answer (score 4):

SELECT * FROM pupil order by score > 100 , score desc